# Created a formula field to populate phone number based on record type

Tags: apex, formula-field

Need to populate contact or user phone number based on the record type:

Create a formula field like this and not able to save

```
IF( OR( RecordType.Name = "Internal"
           ( User__r.MobilePhone ||  User__r.Phone )
       )
     OR( RecordType.Name = "External"
           ( Contact__r.CellPhone__c || Contact__r.HomePhone || Contact__r.Phone  )
       )
  )
```

Comment: welcome to SFSE; please see [ask] on getting  the most from the Community. In your case, please use [edit] and include the error message you are getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mixing logical operators in formulas (`OR()` and `||`, `AND()` and `&&`) is not recommended because it's easy to make mistakes and harder to read. Pick one variety, and stick with it.

`OR()` and `AND()` have commas between each argument, and `IF()` requires 3 arguments (the conditional expression, the value if true, the value if false).

When you have a field whose value you're checking more than once, consider using `CASE()` instead of a chain of `IF()`

ex.

```
IF(
    RecordType.Name = "Internal",
    Owner.MobilePhone,
    IF(
        RecordType.Name = "External",
        Contact__r.Phone
        "" /* You must always have something for the third argument */
    )
)
```

could become

```
CASE(RecordType.DeveloperName,
    "Internal", Owner.MobilePhone,
    "External", Contact__r.Phone,
    "" /* Still need a default "else" value */
)
```

If you want to specify multiple potential values (moving on to the next option if the current option is null), then you need to use a chain of `IF()` e.g.

```
IF(
    NOT(ISBLANK(Contact__r.CellPhone__c)),
    Contact__r.CellPhone__c,
    IF(
        NOT(ISBLANK(Contact__r.HomePhone__c)),
        Contact__r.HomePhone__c,
        /* and so on... */
)
```

As always, [the documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions.htm) is a good thing to reference if you're not sure how something works.

#### +edit:

`BLANKVALUE()` could be chained instead of `IF()` when you're looking for the first non-null value, and save some typing.

```
BLANKVALUE(
    Contact__r.CellPhone__c, 
    BLANKVALUE(
        Contact__r.HomePhone__c,
        Contact__r.Phone
    )
)
```

Comment: Tried   CASE(RecordType.Name,
    "Internal",  User__r.Phone ,
    "External", Contact__r.Phone,
  ) but getting a Error: Syntax error. Found ')'

Comment: @sfdcdeveloper Like I mentioned in the comment in my example, you need the default "else" value at the end. Have you read the documentation on `CASE()`?

Comment: yes I did but not sure how to add blank in else value

Comment: @sfdcdeveloper I had thought that `BLANKVALUE()` did that, but I was mistken. I've edited my answer to correct that.

Comment: even though the field has value it's not pulling the value for phone and it's showing blank

Comment: Changed to recordtype.developername it worked... thanks drek

Answer (score 0):

The expressions

```
( User__r.MobilePhone ||  User__r.Phone )
```

and

```
( Contact__r.CellPhone__c || Contact__r.HomePhone || Contact__r.Phone  )
```

are invalid as they imply that each field is a Boolean (checkbox) - which as they are phone numbers, are most likely not

you will need something like

```
(NOT(ISBLANK (User__r.MobilePhone)) ||  NOT(ISBLANK(User__r.Phone)) )
```